# Java casting int[] to byte[] without conversions

Tags: java, arrays, casting

Is there any way to do a kind of static cast between an `int[]` and `byte[]` ?

What i want is just to get a reference to the `int[]` as a `byte[]` without making any numeric conversions between them and, if it is possible, without having to make a copy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any way to do a kind of static cast between an int[] and byte[] ?

Short answer, no.

But you could wrap the `byte[]` in a [`ByteBuffer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html) and get an`IntBuffer` from it, or just use its `getInt()/putInt()` methods.

In many cases, this would meet your requirements, even if not exactly what you ask for.

Something like:

```
byte[] bytes ...;
ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes); // No copy, changes are reflected

int foo = buffer.getInt(0); // get int value from buffer

foo *= 2; 
buffer.putInt(0, foo); // write int value to buffer

// Or perhaps 
IntBuffer intBuffer = buffer.asIntBuffer(); // Creates an int "view" (no copy)
int bar = intBuffer.get(0);
intBuffer.set(0, bar);
```

The byte order of the byte buffer when working with multi-byte values, like `int` can be controlled using:

```
buffer.order(ByteOrder.BIG_ENDIAN); // Default is platform specific, I believe
```

Answer (score 0):

They are different kinds of objects who can't be cast the way you want. Neither is a subtype of the other. You have 2 different classes (not primitives).

Answer (score 0):

Your question is unclear, what do you want to do with data that doesn't fit?

One approach would be to create a utility class that lets you treat it that way.

i.e. :

```
public class ByteWrapper {
    int[] data;

    byte get(int i) {
       return (byte)data[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem is that i'm using legacy code that uses int[] to actually store bytes. For the application that is not a problem since it directly writes the int[] to disk with a FileOutputStream.